# Memory issue with App Engine and Firestore

Tags: java, performance, google-app-engine, google-cloud-firestore, jvm

I'm developing a MS with `Kotlin` and Micronaut which access a Firestore database. When I run this MS locally I can make it work with 128M because it's very simple just read and write data to Firestore, and not big amounts of data, really small data like this:

```
{
    "project": "DUMMY",
    "columns": [
        {
            "name": "TODO",
            "taskStatus": "TODO"
        },
        {
            "name": "IN_PROGRESS",
            "taskStatus": "IN_PROGRESS"
        },
        {
            "name": "DONE",
            "taskStatus": "DONE"
        }
    ],
    "tasks": {}
}
```

I'm running this in App Engine Standard in a F1 instance (256 MB    600 MHz) with this properties in my app.yaml

```
runtime: java11
instance_class: F1 # 256 MB     600 MHz
entrypoint: java -Xmx200m -jar MY_JAR.jar
service: data-connector
env_variables:
  JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: "-Xmx230m"
  GAE_MEMORY_MB: 128M

automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
  max_idle_instances: 1
```

I know all that properties for handling memory are not necessary but I was desperate trying to make this work and just tried a lot of solutions because my first error message was:

```
Exceeded soft memory limit of 256 MB with 263 MB after servicing 1 requests total. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml.
```

The error below is not fixed with the properties in the `app.yaml`, but now everytime I make a call to return that `JSON` I get this error

```
2020-04-10 12:09:15.953 CEST
While handling this request, the process that handled this request was found to be using too much memory and was terminated. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may have a memory leak in your application or may be using an instance with insufficient memory. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml.
```

It always last longer in the first request, I think due to some Firestore configuration, but the thing is that I cannot make that work, always getting the same error.

Do you have any idea what I could be doing wrong or what I need to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR The problem was I tried to used a very small instance for a simple application, but even with that I needed more memory.

Ok, a friend helped me with this. I was using a very small instance and even when I didn't get the error of memory limit it was a memory problem.

Updating my instance to a F2 (512 MB    1.2 GHz) solved the problem and testing my app with siege resulted in a very nice performance:

```
Transactions:               5012 hits
Availability:             100.00 %
Elapsed time:              59.47 secs
Data transferred:           0.45 MB
Response time:              0.30 secs
Transaction rate:          84.28 trans/sec
Throughput:             0.01 MB/sec
Concurrency:               24.95
Successful transactions:        3946
Failed transactions:               0
Longest transaction:            1.08
Shortest transaction:           0.09
```

My sysops friends tells me that this instances are more for python scripting code and things like that, not JVM REST servers.

Comment: Yeah, that was expected. I'm curious what the 128M meant whey you said "When I run this MS locally I can make it work with 128M". Was it the total memory consumed by the process? How did you measure it? Also, I don't really know GCP much but it seems that the `GAE_MEMORY_MB` env var should be set automatically by the runtime (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml) and there were you setting it manually to `128M` (and your Xmx was significantly higher: 230M)

Comment: I ran it with Xmx and inspect the memory with visualvm and everything was fine but my error was to onlt check the heap values skipping both metaspace and the fact that probably the container in app engine doesn't allow me to use all the 256Mb of memory. And regarding the `GAE_MEMORY_MB` I'm using the standard environment not the flexible (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/runtime), and probably I'm understanding it wrong but I think that says is the memory used for the java application not the container.